# jQuery does not work when reload the page content via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap to display a popover, until there is with all this code below everything works normal.

```
$(".emoticons").popover({
    html : true, 
    placement : 'bottom',
    animation : true,
    delay: { show: 100, hide: 500 },
    content: function() {return $('.emoticonimg').html();
    }
});
```

I only need to load the content of the page via ajax, then I changed the code because when I load the content dynamically I need to delegate events, changed the code and it looked like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.emoticons',function()
{
 $(".emoticons").popover({
    html : true, 
    placement : 'bottom',
    animation : true,
    delay: { show: 100, hide: 500 },
    content: function() {return $('.emoticonimg').html();
    }
 });
});
```

Now my troubles started. The code works however when I click the first time it does not work, so it works when I click more than once on the link. What to do?

Comment: Not a very elegant solution but you could put it in a function and call that in the callback of your ajax function. You'd probably have to unbind first if there are already `.emoticons` on the page...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's happening is that when you are clicking on the `.emoticons` and executing your `popover` function, it is at that moment that you are binding it to your click. That's why it doesn't work the first time, but it works afterwards. It starts listening to the `click` event after that.

Ideally, the solution is to run the `.popover` function when the new content is loaded (on your AJAX callback).

If you want to just copy paste my code and see if it works, you can do this:

```
$('body').on('click','.emoticons',function()
{
// Convert this element into a popover and then display it
 $(this).popover({
    html : true, 
    placement : 'bottom',
    animation : true,
    delay: { show: 100, hide: 500 },
    content: function() {
      return $('.emoticonimg').html();
    }
 }).popover('toggle');
});
```

But, I would NOT recommend this code specifically, since you are re-initializing your popover every time you click on it.

It's better and more clear if you bind all popovers after your AJAX request is done:

```
$.ajax( "BlaBlaBla.php" )
  .done(function() {
    // Convert all emoticons to popovers
    $(".emoticons").popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'bottom',
        animation : true,
        delay: { show: 100, hide: 500 },
        content: function() {
           return $('.emoticonimg').html();
        }
     });
  });
```

Comment: You are right in what he said, the problem is that it only works when I click the first time, not the second onwards displays the popover

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work the first time because the first click if firing off the body onclick handler which binds your popover.

Try something like this in your $(document).ready() function.

```
$(".emoticons").click(function(){

  $(this).popover({
    html : true, 
    placement : 'bottom',
    animation : true,
    delay: { show: 100, hide: 500 },
    content: function() {return $('.emoticonimg').html();
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: did not work...only works when I do the second click

Comment: I said try something like this - no one is just going to write code for you.

Comment: This will not work as it only binds when the DOM is loaded and not after an ajax call when new content is added.

Comment: So instead insert it in the ajax callback so it's bound appropriately.